# using a function as a parameter

Tags: javascript, html, function, syntax, parameter-passing

let me first say that I indeed began by searching and there was a very similar question, but it was sufficiently different that I remain confused.

Disclaimer: I'm making a Rock Paper Scissors game for a homework assignment and just have a quick question about appropriate javascript function/parameter passing.

I have a function called opponentRandom() that returns a randomized "rock or paper or scissors" value as the opponent's (computer's) choice.

I have another function compareChoices() that compares your value (determined by an "onclick" in the html document) with the value from the opponentRandom() function.

Now, inside the table where the game resides, one of the table data (to give you guys an example of how clicking one of the pictures is supposed to work) is as follows:

```
<td onclick="comparisonChoices('paper', 'opponentRandomizer()**;**');">
    <img src="paper.jpg" alt="paper" />
</td>
```

Now, the first parameter in the comparison is supposed to be your choice, and I would really like if I could easily just call the opponentRandom function inside the compareChoices function inside the td onclick, because then the the random result would be considered inside the compareChoices function.

Does this work? Are you allowed to just throw a function inside another called function, as a parameter? the opponentRandom function does indeed return either a rock, paper, scissors value, and the comparison function then either determines whether you won, lost, or tied. I don't know the appropriate syntax or if I can even do this, and I haven't yet integrated the javascript into my html and I don't know any easy way to implement it until I have all the functions necessary for the game to run.

TL;DR - Can you put a function that returns a value inside another function being called as a onclick="function(param,'function()');" ?

Also,should the bolded semi-colon I have above be there? (EDIT: the ** ** is not showing up as bolded, but I am talking about the semi-colon surrounded by the ** **)

Comment: Yes you can put a function in a function call parameter, which passes the inner function's return into the outer function as the parameter, but you must remove the quotes. By quoting it, you're passing in the literal string `opponentRandomizer()`, not the function call.  And remove the `;`.

Comment: `comparisonChoices('paper', opponentRandomizer())`

Comment: JavaScript is a very flexible language that actually allows you to pass function references (without the `()`), but that doesn't appear to be your case.

Comment: I cannot thank you enough, you are a scholar and a gentleman

Comment: Or, as in the answer below, you can just call the opponent function inside `comparisonChoices()`...

Comment: It's good practice not to put complicated code inside HTML; best practice would be to do `onclick="userClicked('paper')"` or `onclick="userClicked(this)"` (and use `this` to determine what was clicked)

Answer (score 2):

what's wrong with:

```
function comparisonChoices(selection) {
    other_selection = opponentRandomizer();
    etc....
}
```

?

Comment: Ah, very true. Didn't think about that. Is there any downside to what I am doing by passing the parameter vs. doing what you did? Just curious.

Comment: This method would call only opponentrandomizer(), since it's embedded inside the function. Passing it as a parameter would potentially let you have multiple different randomizer functions and you select which one you want to use at the time you do the function call.